# Excel Filter Formula/Function - return the first row from the filter formula/function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi so I have a function as following;

```
=FILTER(A:M,(B:B=P4) * (C:C=Q4) * (F:F>=R4))
```

the formula returns an array with all conditions met.

I was wonder if there is a way to return the only first row from the filtered array?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use at `@` symbol to return only first value (not full row). If you want to return full row then you need Index function then define row number like `1`.

```
=@FILTER(A:M,(B:B=P4) * (C:C=Q4) * (F:F>=R4))
```

Use above formula to return only first value. and below will return first row.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A:M,(B:B=P4) * (C:C=Q4) * (F:F>=R4)),1)
```

Comment: Hi thank you! I might not phrasing this very well...but This is getting very close! my filtered formula returns multiple rows and columns, is that a way to return the first row only, I used your suggestion and it only returns first row of the first column. Again thank you so much!

Comment: @KaiPeng Can you please check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just `INDEX` it.

`=INDEX(FILTER(A:M, ((B:B=P4)*(C:C=Q4)*(F:F>=R4))), 1)`